# How to use UUIDs with Hibernate as a field?

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I'm trying to use generated UUIDs without @Id annotation, because my primary key is something else. The application does not generate an UUID, do you have an idea?

This is my declaration:

```
@Column(name = "APP_UUID", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String uuid;
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.0 with Oracle10g.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I use the last answer as a fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this it may help

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
private String uuid;
```

read this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-identifier) read hibernate documents it is possible

Comment: I used your solution without the @Id annotation. No improvement :/

Comment: Eclipse throws an error:"This class has a composite primary key. It must use an ID class."

Comment: @Engineer - you should add more explanations to your answer. Links can become obsolete. It's definitely appropriate to cite sources, but you should provide a proper, full response.

Comment: `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: hibernate-uuid`

Comment: isn't it possible to have it generated without @Id annotation. I dont want my column to be a primary key.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

Check the Javadoc of `GeneratedValue`:

> Provides for the specification of generation strategies for the values of **primary keys**.

With other words - it is not possible with just an annotation to initialize a 'none ID' attribute.

But you can use `@PrePersist`:

```
@PrePersist
public void initializeUUID() {
    if (uuid == null) {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not because your UUID is a primary key that it's mandatory to have it annoted with `@GeneratedValue`.

For example, you can do something like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
   @Id
   private String uuid;

   public MyClass() {}

   public MyClass (String uuid) {
      this.uuid = uuid;
   }
}
```

And in your app, generate a UUID before saving your entity :

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
em.persist(new MyClass(uuid)); // em : entity manager
```

Comment: I know the chance to have an UUID twice is very unlikely, but it could happen. That's why I wanted hibernate to manage UUIDs. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hibernate does _nothing_ to prevent an ID - conflict (especially it does not generate a new value if the first value exists in the database already)